# Не могу понять, куда пропадает символ

Tags: c++, файлы, вывод, ввод

Имеется код:

```
while (!fin.eof())
{
    while (ch != '\n')
    {
        fin.get(ch);
        cout << "ch: " << ch << endl; // проверка, какой извлечен символ
        if (isalnum(ch)) name += ch; // из символов собираю слово
        if (name.size() != 0 && !isalnum(ch) && i != 4)
        {
            v[i++] = name;
            name.clear(); // очищаю строку string
        }
    }
    fin.get(ch);
    i = 0; // для записи второй строки поверх первой
}
```

У меня имеется текстовый файл, где записаны некоторые слова в таком формате:

```
xxxxx: abcde, dsadassad, zdadassda
zzzzz: kkklm, njjjkmzmn, zz13mmsdk
```

Мне нужно записать 4 слова отдельно из каждой строки в массив.
Так вот, после цикла во второй строчке у первого слова пропадает первый символ. Думаю, что это из за того, что дважды вызывается fin.get(ch): в конце цикла и во вложенном цикле. Но я не знаю как с этим бороться - если я просто пишу fin.get(); ch = '0'; (для того что бы снова пошел вложенный цикл), бесконечно печатаются нули.
Подскажите пожалуйста, в чем проблема.

Answer (score 1):

Проблема решена. Я изменил так:

```
while (!fin.eof())
{
    if (ch == '\n') // если перевод строки достигнут
    {
        ch = 0; // обнуляем для продолжения ввода
        i = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        fin.get(ch);
        cout << "ch: " << ch << endl;
        if (isalnum(ch)) 
            name += ch;
        if (name.size() != 0 && !isalnum(ch) && i != 4)
        {
            v[i++] = name;
            name.clear();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Все равно неправильно. При EOF строка


      cout << "ch: " << ch << endl;


у Вас тоже будет выполняться.

Всегда надо проверять результат `fin.get(ch)`.

Answer (score 0):

А зачем возиться с символами, если можно разбивать строки на слова? И проще, и удобней.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void split_string(char* str, const char* delim, int (*cb)(const char*))
{
    char* word = strtok(str, delim);
    while( word ) {
        if( *word ) {
            cb(word);
        }
        word = strtok(NULL, delim);
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    const char* delimiters = " ,:\n";
    char buf[80];
    FILE* f = stdin;

    while( !feof(f) ) {
        fflush(f);
        fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), f);
        split_string(buf, delimiters, puts);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Неправильно.

Первое слово из последней перед EOF строки лишний раз напечатается

(fgets() надо проверять на EOF). 

--

Т.е.

     while (fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), f))
       split_string(buf, delimiters, puts);

и все (в данном контексте будет работать). 

--

Только не забывайте о побочном эффекте -- `strtok()` безнадежно портит содержимое своего первого аргумента (в данном случае `buf[]`).

Comment: > Неправильно.

Да, действительно, спасибо за уточнение. Вчера лень было проверять на реальном файле, проверил только в консоли. Но основная моя идея была в функции split_string. Как получена передаваемая в нее строка - в общем случае не имеет значения. Принцип единственной ответственности.

Я только не пойму, почему цикл нормально работает, даже когда файл не кончается символом новой строки. Почему последняя строка тоже обрабатывается правильно? Или fgets, встретив EOF, сначала возвращает строку, и только при следующем вызове - NULL? Это все объяснило бы.

Comment: @VadimTukaev, если `fgets` что-то поместила в `buf`, то вернет `buf` (даже если ввод завершился EOF), иначе, встретив EOF, вернет `NULL`.

Код примерно такой

    char *fgets (char *buf, size_t size, FILE *f) {
       if (feof(f)) 
         return 0;
       size_t i = 0;
       int c;
     
       while (i < size - 1 && (c = fgetc(f)) != EOF;)
         if ((buf[i++] = c) == '\n')
            break;
       buf[i] = 0;
       return i ? buf : 0;
    }

--

Кстати, в консоли будет то же самое, потому что при EOF fgets-то вернет NULL, но предыдущее содержимое буфера останется.

Всегда проверяйте.

Comment: Кстати, а зачем Вы постоянно пишете 

    fflush(input_file);

IMHO (по крайней мере в Linux) он *ничего не делает* (хотя в manpage и написано, что сбрасывает входной буфер, но мне ни в одном "тесте" добиться зримого результата не удалось).

Comment: Спасибо, этого я про fgets не знал. Это многое упрощает...

А fflush нужен для корректного ввода с консоли (во всяком случае, виндозной). Иначе предыдущие нажатия могут остаться в буфере клавиатуры. Я пару раз из-за этого получил баг, теперь дую на воду.

Comment: @VadimTukaev, я в очередной раз попробовал разобраться, как же работает `fflush(stdin);`?

Пробовал в win7 в `cmd` и там же в Emacs eshell (эмулятор терминала), а также в Linux. 

Идея теста:

     while (1) {
        fflush(stdin);
        fgets(buf, ....); puts(buf);
        sleep(3);
        // а вот здесь можно успеть вбить несколько строк,
        // которые по идее должны пропасть
     }


Код программки и результат (копипасты с экранов) положил в http://pastebin.com/vB7BeXSU

--

Резюме -- **не работает.**

Только в eshell все же сбрасывает все введенные символы, кроме первой строки.